# Como simplificar um problema para pegar os nomes dos meses do ano?

Tags: c, algoritmo, otimização

Estou a começar a programar em C e realizei este problema cujo enunciado é o seguinte:

> Escreva um exercício que solicite o número de um mês ao utilizador e que imprima no ecrã o nome do mês. Por exemplo, o utilizador introduz 1 e o programa escreve “Janeiro". Caso o utilizador introduza um número que não corresponda a qualquer mês, deve escrever uma mensagem de erro apropriada no ecrã.

Para já, ainda só sei o básico (`if`, `else`...), como tal, fiz assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int mes;
    printf("Numero do mes: \n");
    scanf("%d",&mes);
    if (mes == 1)
        printf("Janeiro\n");
    else if (mes == 2)
        printf("Fevereiro\n");
    else if (mes == 3)
        printf("Marco\n");
    else if (mes == 4)
        printf("Abril\n");
    else if (mes == 5)
        printf("Maio\n");
    else if (mes == 6)
        printf("Junho\n");
    else if (mes == 7)
        printf("Julho\n");
    else if (mes == 8)
        printf("Agosto\n");
    else if (mes == 9)
        printf("Setembro\n");
    else if (mes == 10)
        printf("Outubro\n");
    else if (mes == 11)
        printf("Novembro\n");
    else if (mes == 12)
        printf("Dezembro\n");
    else if ((mes<1) || (mes>12))
        printf("Erro\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Como posso resolver este mesmo problema com um código mais simplificado?

Comment: Pesquise pelo comando switch/case.

Comment: Note que em seu programa você testa todos os números de mês válidos (1 a 12) portanto não há necessidade do último if.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 8):

Algumas coisas aí estão sobrando, mas a maior simplificação é usar um *array*  no lugar de um `if`. Você pode colocar todos os nomes nesse *array*  e acessar através do índice dele conforme a digitação. A validação precisa ser feita antes. Note que retirei algumas redundância, afinal simplificação implicam nisso.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int mes;
    printf("Numero do mes: ");
    scanf("%d", &mes);
    if (mes < 1 || mes > 12) {
        printf("\nErro");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\n%s", (char *[12]){ "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Marco", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro" }[mes - 1]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AK5WfX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/halmjzlh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/GetMonthName.c).

Comment: Não seria melhor usar uma função que retornasse o mês escolhido?

Comment: @gato, não sei, depende do que se quer fazer, em um exercício que faz quase anda e quer ser simples uma função parece ser canhão para matar passarinho. Há um forte justificativa para usar a função?

Comment: Aumentar a legibilidade e evitar a repetição do array, o princípio da função é apenas retornar o mês escolhido.

Comment: Não há repetição, legibilidade é discutível. Em um exercício que queira ser simples o ato de criar uma função piora a legibilidade, e é *overengineering*.

Answer (score 5):

Armazene os meses num array: `const char *strings[] = {"Janeiro","Fevereiro"...};`, e acesse o respectivo mês com a entrada do usuário:

```
printf("Numero do mes: \n");
scanf("%d",&mes);

printf("%s", meses[mes-1]);
```

Comment: Por que esse "i" no printf? Ele não está definido...

Comment: Caramba! Nem tinha percebido rs.

Answer (score -1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
    int mes;
    printf("Numero do mes: ");
    scanf("%d", &mes);
    const char *meses[] = {"Janeiro", ...};

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if(mes == i) {
            printf(meses[i]);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Oi, Juliana, da uma olhada nesse tópico e entenda porque você pode levar pontos negativos com respostas no formato da sua (Em apenas código): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7634/voc%C3%AAs-acham-isso-certo?cb=1